# Save the data coming from a riverpod controller in a different state

Tags: flutter, state, riverpod

I have a riverpod controller which i use to make api call and fetch the data and use display in my screen.

```
final imagesByCamIdControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<
ImagesByCamIdController, ImagesByCamIdState>((ref) {
final cameraService = ref.watch(cameraDetailsProvider);
return ImagesByCamIdController(const ImagesByCamIdState(), cameraService);
});
class ImagesByCamIdController extends StateNotifier<ImagesByCamIdState> {
ImagesByCamIdController(super.state, this.service);
final CameraDetailsRepositoryImpl service;
Future getImagesByCamId(projectId, cameraId, {searchDate = ''}) async {
state = state.copyWith(isFetching: true);
final result = await service.imagesByCameraId(projectId, cameraId,
    searchDate: searchDate);
result.fold((l) {
  // error handle
  state = state.copyWith(isFetching: false, errorMessage: l.message);
}, (r) {
  state =
      state.copyWith(isFetching: false, imagesByCamId: AsyncValue.data(r));
});
}}
```

here is how i use it in my screen:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  ref.read(imagesByCamIdControllerProvider.notifier).getImagesByCamId(
      widget.projectId, widget.cameraId,
      searchDate: _searchDate);
});
}
```

then assign it in my Widget build:

```
final imagesByCameraIdData = ref.watch(
    imagesByCamIdControllerProvider.select((value) => value.imagesByCamId));
```

Now what i want is that the data coming from riverpod controller must be stored in another provider. n i will use that provider to display and change state. Reason is i dont want to make api calls every time i change state.

How can i save the data coming from imagesByCamIdControllerProvider in another state probably a statenotiferprovider n use that to display images n change state?

Comment: You should have that "other provider" watch the first provider directly.  That's the whole point of data dependencies.

Comment: I also need to push state to it (other provider). not able to figure out how. Can you please provide an example for me